# Concatenate XML Attributes SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery-sql

I have an XML data set that which defines a list of **Customers** and all the **Products** the customer has purchased

```xml
<Info>
  <Customer CustomerId="1">
    <Product Name="A" Cost="20" />
    <Product Name="C" Cost="30" />
  </Customer>
  <Customer CustomerId="2">
    <Product Name="A" Cost="23" />
    <Product Name="B" Cost="46" />
  </Customer>
  <Customer CustomerId="3">
    <Product Name="B" Cost="32" />
    <Product Name="C" Cost="64" />
  </Customer>
</Info>
```

I want to list the customer and their products in a separate query like this

| Customer | Products |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A $20, C $30 |
| 2 | A $23, B $46 |
| 3 | B $32, C $64 |

Being new to XQuery in SQL Server I am struggling to find a solution. Over the past couple days I have come up with a query that looks like this

```sql
declare @xml xml;

...

select
    Info.Customer.value('@CustomerID[1]', 'int') as CustomerID,
    Info.Customer.query('./*') as Products
from
    @xml.nodes('info/Customer') Info(Customer);
```

Which produces the following results

| Customer | Products |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `<Product Name="A", Cost="20" />, <Product Name="C", Cost="30" />` |
| 2 | `<Product Name="A", Cost="23" />, <Product Name="B", Cost="46" />` |
| 3 | `<Product Name="B", Cost="32" />, <Product Name="C", Cost="64" />` |

For those of you that are familiar with with using `FOR XML` to concatenate rows using the following pattern, I want to make clear that this **is not** what I am asking for.

```sql
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    (
        SELECT Name + ' $' + Cost
        FROM Product
        WHERE Product.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    )
FROM Customer
```

The query I use to produce the `<Info>...</Info>` data set runs in a fraction of the time and has all the data I need, I'm just wondering if there is any way to concatenate the attributes in the same manner?

Comment: FYI SQL Server 2008R2 has been *completely* unsupported for almost 2 years, and SQL Server 2012 is soon to be completely unsupported too. I strongly support getting your instances upgraded.

Comment: @lptr Is there something stopping you posting that as an answer?

Comment: @lptr, That works great! That answers my question and more. Thanks for expressing the answer in multiple forms. The XQuery with the `if` statement runs twice as fast as the `stuff`. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @lptr in the comments, you can use either of the following solutions

```sql
declare @xml xml = N'<Info>
  <Customer CustomerId="1">
    <Product Name="A" Cost="20" />
    <Product Name="C" Cost="30" />
  </Customer>
  <Customer CustomerId="2">
    <Product Name="A" Cost="23" />
    <Product Name="B" Cost="46" />
  </Customer>
  <Customer CustomerId="3">
    <Product Name="B" Cost="32" />
    <Product Name="C" Cost="64" />
  </Customer>
</Info>';

select
  i.c.value('@CustomerId', 'int'),
  stuff(
    i.c.query('
      for $p in Product
      return text{concat(", ", $p/@Name, " $", $p/@Cost)}
    ').value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2,''),

  i.c.query('
    for $p in Product
    return text{concat($p/@Name, " $", $p/@Cost, if ($p is Product[last()]) then "" else ", ")}
  ')
from @xml.nodes('Info/Customer') as i(c);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e94074c442044fedf95442982e63d553)